# Checking for an internet connection: IEnumerator with lambda expression error

Tags: c#

I am getting a compile time error in this code that states the following:

```
Cannot convert `lambda expression' to delegate type `System.Action<bool>' because
some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate
return type
```

Here are my methods. I want to be able to return True or False depending on if there is an internet connection or not. How can I go about doing this.

```
private bool IsAbleToCallMethods () {
        StartCoroutine(ConnectedToInternet((isConnected)=>{
            if (isConnected) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }));
    }

private IEnumerator ConnectedToInternet(Action<bool> action) {
        // Issue a request to google and see if the request returned
        // any errors or not, this will determine if you were able
        // to reach google via an internet connection
        WWW www = new WWW("http://google.com");
        yield return www;
        if (www.error != null) {
            action (false);
        } else {
            action (true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing `if (isConnected)`, but `isConnected` cannot be tested this way because it doesn't return `bool`, it returns `void`, if you want a delegate that returns anything other than `void` its type should be `Func`, in this case if you want a delegate taking a `bool` an returning a `bool` it should be `Func<bool, bool>`.

Have a look at this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/46279/delegate-vs-action-vs-func.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link, explained it nicely.

Answer (score 3):

`Action` does not return anything. You need to use `Func<bool,bool>` instead.First `bool` is for the parameter and the last argument is the return type.

```
private IEnumerator ConnectedToInternet(Func<bool,bool> action)
```